# PowerBi - Sum measure

Tags: powerbi

I am struggling to get my measure to SUM correctly.

In general if revenue is blank fill the blank with Budget number.

My formula so far:

```
Revenue = IF(ISBLANK([TotalRevenue]),[TotalBudget],[TotalRevenue])
```

I have tried this with a column but it wont work because my budgeted results are from a different table vs where my revenue is.

Also tried with

HASONEFILTER -

```
Measure = 
VAR TotalRevenue = SUM(Paysuite[NET_REVENUE])
VAR TotalBudget = SUM(Budget[Bgt Revenue])
RETURN
IF(HASONEFILTER('Date'[Fiscal Year]),IF(ISBLANK([TotalRevenue]),[TotalBudget],[TotalRevenue]),SUMX(FILTER(Budget,Budget[TotalBudget]),[TotalBudget]))
```

example

```
JAN - 1
FEB - 2
MAR - 3
APR (bgt) - 1
MAY (bgt) - 1
```

Total comes to 6 where expected result should be 8

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked it out - I had the wrong field in hasonefilter - should be something that we wont use as a filter at all

```
Measure = 

IF(
    HASONEFILTER(P[EZ.Count]),
    IF(
        ISBLANK([TotalRevenue]),
        [TotalBudget],
        [TotalRevenue]
    ),
    SUMX(
        VALUES(Budget[Bgt Revenue]),
        [Revenue]
    )
)
```